# JQuery, Click and Edit TD with Date to a New Date

Tags: jquery, click, uidatepicker, html-table

I just wanted to know if this is possible.

i Have a Table like this

```
Site Name   Type    Address City    Lat Long    Fault Time
ISB056  Spur    aaaa    Isl 73.0    33.64   13:14 PM
```

What i want is to Click the Last TD (with the TH Fault Time) and have a datepicker ask a new date and have it inserted into the TD instead of the previous date.

I cant select the TD and use .text() to insert the new date. But how to call the Jquery UI Datepicker on this item..

Comment: do you want new `date` or `time`?

Comment: Eh... the `datepicker` can't be used to select **time** like your data is suggesting...

Comment: :( ohh yeah ..

Any Recommendations ???

Comment: You don't really need something that fancy to simply let the user change the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution would be to put the date in a text field (INPUT) inside the TD. This way you can use the date picker with the default behavior (click on the text field triggers the date picker).

Then make your text field read-only and style it so that it doesn't look like a text field (if that is what you want).

Comment: You don't really have to make all those `textbox`, [look](http://jsfiddle.net/FMuut/)